# Persistent references in Python

Tags: python, persistence, pickle

I would like my program to store datas for later uses. Until now, not any problem: there is much ways of doing this in Python.

Things get a little more complicated because I want to keep references between instances. If a list X is a list Y (they have the same ID, modify one is modify the other), it should be true the next time I load the datas (another session of the program which has stopped in the meantime).

I know a solution : the pickle module keeps tracks of references and will remember that my X and Y lists are exactly the same (not only their contents, but their references).

Still, the problem using pickle is that it works if you dump every data in a single file. Which is not really clever if you have a large amount of data.

Do you know another way to handle this problem?

Comment: From Python 2.6 there is the JSON module, which could be fitting your needs.

Comment: `the problem using pickle is that it works if you dump every data in a single file. Which is not really clever if you have a large amount of data.` How big is your data?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing to do is probably to wrap up all your state you wish to save in a dictionary (keyed by variable name, perhaps, or some other unique but predictable identifier), then pickle and unpickle that dictionary. The objects within the dictionary will share references between one another like you want:

```
>>> class X(object):
...     # just some object to be pickled
...     pass
... 
>>> l1 = [X(), X(), X()]
>>> l2 = [l1[0], X(), l1[2]]
>>> state = {'l1': l1, 'l2': l2}
>>> saved = pickle.dumps(state)
>>> restored = pickle.loads(saved)
>>> restored['l1'][0] is restored['l2'][0]
True
>>> restored['l1'][1] is restored['l2'][1]
False
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommand using `shelve` over pickle. It has higher level functionnality, and is simpler to use.

http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html

If you have performance issue because you manipulate very large amount of data, you may try other librairies like pyTables:

http://www.pytables.org/moin

Answer (score 0):

ZODB is developed to save persistent python objects and all references. Just inherit your class from Persistent and have a fun. http://www.zodb.org/